# Is there any command for delete rails generated using scaffold files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I want to delete all stuff related to rails generate scaffold at once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this command and enjoying......

```
 rails destroy scaffold scaffoldname
```

scaffold name = The name of generated scaffold which you generate..

Answer (score 2):

```
rails d scaffold yourscaffoldname
```

(In your terminal)